# Linear Least Squares Differentiated - from Deep Learning (Goodfellow)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have been working through Goodfellow's textbook (which is free online) as it is a requirement for a course I'm taking. However, I have tried to work through some of the calculations not shown in the book myself, and have got stuck on this one, which is from "4.5 Example: Linear Least Squares" equation (4.21). I am trying to differentiate the function below, f(**x**), but am having trouble. Making some assumptions, I have managed to get the correct answer, but I am wondering if the working is right. Thanks!

"Suppose we want to find the value of x that minimizes:"

f(**x**) = $\frac{1}{2}$||***A*** **x** - **b**||$_2^2$

*rewriting*

= (***A*** **x** - **b**)$^T$(***A*** **x** - **b**)

*expanding the brackets*

= $\frac{1}{2}$((***A*** **x**)$^T$***A*** **x** - **b**$^T$***A*** **x** - (***A*** **x**)$^T$**b** + **b$^T$b**)

= $\frac{1}{2}$((***A*** **x**)$^T$***A*** **x** - 2**b**$^T$***A*** **x** + **b$^T$b**)

let: u(**x**) = (***A*** **x**)$^T$ ; v(**x**) = ***A*** **x**

then: u'(**x**) = ***A***$^T$ --- *not sure if this is right ?*

v'(**x**) = ***A***

*therefore, employing the chain rule:*

f '(**x**) = $\frac{1}{2}$ ( ***A***$^T$***A*** **x** + (***A*** **x**)$^T$***A*** - 2**b**$^T$***A*** )

*and* (***A*** **x**)$^T$***A*** = ***A***$^T$***A*** **x**

f '(**x**) = $\frac{1}{2}$ ( 2 ***A***$^T$***A*** **x** - 2**b**$^T$***A*** )

= ***A***$^T$***A*** **x** - **b**$^T$***A***

= ***A***$^T$***A*** **x** - ***A***$^T$**b**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term which you are questioning is the scalar product $$s=(Ax)^T(Ax)$$
Define a new variable $\,w=Ax,\,$ then $s=w^Tw\,\,$ whose gradient is easily found
$$\eqalign{
s  &= w^Tw \cr
ds &= 2w^Tdw \cr
s' &= 2w = 2Ax \cr
}$$
Actually, if you use the variable $y=(Ax-b),\,$ then the entire problem can be handled as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac{1}{2}y^Ty \cr
df &= y^T\,dy &= y^TA\,dx \cr
f' &= A^Ty &= A^T(Ax-b) \cr
}$$